# Django throws an ImportError on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to get a work project that I git-cloned from work (used in numerous other places, I know the project works fine) to run on my MacBook. I installed Django (via *sudo python setup.py install*), as well as MySQL, the Python MySQL wrapper, and also virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper.

After creating a virtualenv for my project (virtualenv is created fine), and doing a pip install for the project requirements (all of which install into the proper virtualenv directory), an attempt to do a runserver command spits out the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named website-backend
```

Comment: Is `website-backend` an installed app?

Comment: Yes, website-backend is the name of the project that I cloned from git.

Comment: Well the answer would be "no" then, a project is not an app. It would be useful if you could include a more complete bash session so it's clear what directory you're in when you run commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First try to import this library from **python** or **./manage.py shell**.

If that fails **import sys** and check if your lib is in sys path **print sys.path**